# Angular Kendo GridComponent columns ( QueryList<ColumnBase>) mutating when iterated over

Tags: arrays, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to capture the new column order after column reordering (this is being saved on a backend). I have captured the grid component using @ViewChild and listening to the grid column reorder event as documented by kendo `(columnReorder)="onColumnReorder($event)"`. I can see the data grid columns data `QueryList<ColumnBase>` is in the right order inside the `onColumnReorder` method i.e. using `this.grid.columns.toArray();` However when I try to iterate over the grid columns, the properties I am interested in all of a sudden change value inside the forEach / map functions. For example, the orderIndex as the right value on console log `this.grid.columns.toArray()` but once inside the `map / foreach`, the value is 0.

```
export class AppComponent {
  // code omitted
  public onColumnReorder(event: ColumnReorderEvent): void {
    const adjustedColumns = this.adjustedColumns.filter(
      (column) =>
        column.columnKeyValue?.columnValue && column.columnKeyValue.columnKey
    );
    console.debug("[debug] <adjusted.columns>", adjustedColumns);
  }

  private get adjustedColumns(): any[] {
    const gridColumns = this.grid.columns.toArray();
    console.debug("[debug] grid.columns", gridColumns);
    gridColumns.forEach((column: ColumnBase) =>
      console.debug(
        "[debug] grid.columns",
        column.title,
        column.leafIndex,
        column.orderIndex
      )
    );
    return gridColumns.map((column: ColumnBase) => {
      // @ts-ignore
      const { title, field, orderIndex, leafIndex, width } = column;
      return {
        columnKeyValue: {
          columnKey: title,
          columnValue: field
        },
        order: Number(leafIndex) - 1,
        width: width
      };
    });
  }
}
```

I have reproduced the issue on this sample on [code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-robinson-dgrfmw?file=/src/app/app.component.ts).